# Gradient colors ramp Shader Node - Vertical and static (animated object)

Tags: animation, node-editor, color, shader-nodes

I am trying to create an animation similar with this image:
[image]

and this is what I created:
[image]

using this node:
[image]

I'd like the colors to remain in same position while the helix spring is rotating.

This is my result, but I am not satisfied, the colors should be similar with first picture and remain in same position while the helix is rotating:
[image]

Comment: Assuming this is a curve object, you can use UV coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Allen Simpson has commented:

If you use a single cyclic Bezier curve, given thickness with its native *Bevel*, (set in its  *Data* tab > *Geometry* panel,) it is automatically mapped 0->1 in U along its length.

So a node arrangement like this can set the color-ramp's range of colors along its length:

[image]

The *Add* and *Wrap* nodes are optional: changing the 'Add' value shifts the whole range along the curve.

[image]

Comment: ok, Robin, your model looks a liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitle bit better than mine...i have to admit that! :D

Comment: @Chris.. it's a fudge. I have to confess I haven't found the way to make the connections between spirals at an exact tangent. Challenge for you :D.

Comment: me...!!??!!? i am a Blender beginner...still learning every day!!! I cannot even make this nice spirals combine each other looking nicely...i can do both spirals standalone (outer and inner), but no good idea how to connect them that it looks good.

Comment: @Chris I'm learning every day, too. My main reason for being here. External spiral: Curve > Spheric. Internal spiral: Single vert, Screw modifier, so adjustable. Eyeballed, converted to curve, joined, smoothed. Yuk. I want a nice clean mathematical way :D

Comment: so you cleverly rotated your object to hide your ugly connection? ;) :D Damn...you are so clever!!! ok...well...i should not complain about ugly ... ;)

Comment: @Chris Yup! I used to work in the film industry. Stop-motion animation on to 35mm, Important lesson ?... It's all 2D in the end. Only the pixels matter. Whatever it takes. :D

Comment: You are so right. Except…if we start doing holograms. Then they will see your bad connection!!!impressive. Any famous movies you made? Lion King? Aquaman? Avatar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124478/discussion-between-robin-betts-and-chris).

Answer (score 2):

if your spiral is in the origin you can use this node setup:

[image]

Play with the threshold to get your desired result.

and you get this: (seen from above)

[image]

what the setup does is: it calculates the length (x*x + y*y) and checks whether it is inside a given range (threshold) and if it is, it takes the first colorramp, else the second.

sideview:

[image]

sorry for my bad modelling. Modelling is not my strength :(

if you don't get this to work, please provide your blend file, then i can adapt it especially to your needs.